# Spring Boot : Disable AutoConfiguration of all modules

Tags: spring-boot

In Spring Boot, is there a way to prevent Auto Configuration of all modules? Basically am looking for something like `@DisableAutoConfiguration` instead of excluding specific configurations with class names.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? Your question is very succinct but you are potentially throwing away a lot of functionality

Comment: Yes, I know it throws away a lot of functionality, but the reason is I would like to have complete control of all beans and their settings. The only feature I currently need from Spring Boot is deployable jar files with embedded containers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Auto-configuration is enabled by the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation. If you don't want to use auto-configuration, then omit this annotation. Note that `@SpringBootApplication` is itself annotated with `@EnableAutoConfiguration` so you'll have to avoid using it too. Typically, this would leave your main application class annotated with `@ComponentScan` and `@Configuration`.

Comment: Plus 1 for giving the alternatives to (not) using EnableAutoConfiguration or SpringBootApplication.  Thank you.